# Nuxeo: after activating the Anonymous User can't log in

Tags: authentication, anonymous, nuxeo

My goal is to add the anonymous authentication to Nuxeo web ui.

I followed the steps on https://doc.nuxeo.com/nxdoc/how-to-define-public-pages-viewable-by-anonymous-users/.

1. Created anonymous-auth-config.xml with the following content:

```
<component name="org.nuxeo.ecm.platform.login.anonymous.config">
  <!-- Add an Anonymous user -->
  <extension target="org.nuxeo.ecm.platform.usermanager.UserService"
    point="userManager">
    <userManager>
      <users>
        <anonymousUser id="Guest">
          <property name="firstName">Guest</property>
          <property name="lastName">User</property>
        </anonymousUser>
      </users>
    </userManager>
  </extension>
</component>
```

First I copied the file into the C:\Nuxeo\nxserver\config then try folder C:\Nuxeo\templates\common\config.

2. Modified nuxeo.conf and set nuxeo.user.anonymous.enable=true.
3. Restart the application server.

Now I can only enter the web ui as Anonymous user, but can't log in as Administrator or any other valid user.

There is *forceAnonymousLogin=true* query string in the url now by default.

I'm not sure should I change and how the *authenticationChain* as stated in another link: https://doc.nuxeo.com/nxdoc/using-anonymous-authentication/

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: What exact file(s), with their content, did you create? Without this information it's hard to help.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the cookies, because if I clear them from the browser, I can log in once. After "Sign Out" I'm not redirected to the log in screen, but remain in the Home page logged as Anonymous user. After that I can't log in again. Windows 10 installation, same on the Chrome and Opera.

Comment: On StackOverflow the rule is to update your original question to make it clearer rather than add comment after comment. At this time I don't have suggestions, no.

Comment: @FlorentGuillaume I'm new here, sorry. Edited the post, hope it's clearer now. Thanks!